# Identification of red rose with mild fragrance

Tags: identification, roses

This rose has a mild fragrance and this flower is the first bloom of this plant.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to say you're unlikely to get a correct ID for this - there are thousands upon thousands of varieties of rose, from shrubs to climbers to bush HT or bush floribunda, miniatures and patio roses, with  more varieties being bred all the time  - ID is often based not only on the flower form, colour and scent, but also on growth habit of the plant, colour of the foliage, size, shape and colour of thorns. Because yours is a young plant, there aren't many clues in regard to anything other than the single flower you have - there are several roses with similar flowers, many being shrub types

Comment: Rishabh, regarding roses, providing photos of the flower at different stages will help with identification - that is - in bud, first day bloom, third day bloom, etc. As mentioned by others, with so many hundreds of varieties, identification can be difficult, so any additional information would be most helpful. That said, it does look *a lot* like my Rosa “Bordeaux”. If you’re able to update (Edit) your question with additional photos for the next bloom, that would be helpful. Also include a close up of the leaf.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll keep on updating new photos.